# ionic sqlite delete by id, item undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I want to delete a row from sqlite my code is as below:

**app.js**

```
try {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name:"inbox.db",location:'default'});
} catch (error) {
    alert(error);
}

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Messages (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, message TEXT)');
```

**controllers.js**

```
$scope.remove = function(item) {
    var query = "DELETE FROM Messages WHERE id = ?";

    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [item.id]).then(function(res) {
        console.warn('after query >  ' + item.id);
    }, function (err) {
        console.warn('error on deleting freaking off');
        console.error(err);
    });
};
```

and in html file I used `ng-click="remove(item)"`

and I get "undefined" for item.id

Apparently I need to define item first but can't figure out what to do!

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your .html code?

You might have to define item when you populate your list:

```html
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" item="item"></ion-item>
```